# Alternative to hot deck imputation

Tags: data-imputation, interpolation

I use hot deck imputation for a project that I work on. But I'm dissatisfied that it can't come up with new values. If my doner set had thousands of values in it, and they were nicely distributed, then I might just calculate a probability density function and draw instead from that.

**Are there any alternatives that are a bit more creative than simply drawing from a doner set when the size of the doner set is only in the region of 10 to 50? Or occasionally under 10?**

I think so long as the drawn set had the same mean, expected median and variance as the doner set, then I have carte blanche to use whatever system I want.